# Using safeAreaInsets get the top edge of my UIWindow's safe area works in iOS 13, but not iOS 11?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have a method in my portrait-orientation iOS app that attempts to return the value in points of the top edge of the main window's safe area, using [safeAreaInsets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891103-safeareainsets?language=objc):

```
+ (double)screenTopEdge
{
    UIWindow *mainWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {
        return mainWindow.safeAreaInsets.top;
    } else {
        // (Handle older iOS verisons)
    }
}
```

When I run this under **iOS 13**, it works as expected: It returns `44.0` when run on an iPhone X, and `20.0` when run on an iPhone 8 or an iPad Mini.

However, when I run this under **iOS 11**, it returns `0.0`, on all of the aforementioned devices (even though the status bar is shown/visible -- not hidden).

I get this behavior even if I call this method from late in the rendering pipeline for the current view controller, including from the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidAppear` methods.

I've been able to reproduce this on a freshly-created iOS Storyboard-based project in XCode 11.1, so I don't think this behavior is due to any odd configuration in my project.

I've been able to work around this by checking the height of the status bar instead:

```
return [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
```

However, why doesn't the code that uses `safeAreaInsets.top` work as expected under iOS 11? What's the right way to get the top safe area inset of the main application window in iOS 11+?

Comment: i dont remeber right now but i guess safearea was a thing in xcode 10 or ios 12, not sure at all

Comment: Hmm. Per the docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891103-safeareainsets?language=objc), safeAreaInsets is supported in iOS 11.0+. (Under "SDKs" on the right side of the linked page.)

Comment: It is even not implemented under iOS 11. How it returns something?

Comment: @Cy-4AH Why do you think `safeAreaInsets` is not implemented under iOS 11? Is Apple's documentation (linked in my previous comment just above) inaccurate in this case?

Comment: It's implemented since iOS 11 not under

Comment: @Cy-4AH If you mouse over "iOS 11.0+" on the linked page, the text of the tool tip that appears is `Available on iOS 11 and later`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old question, about a very outdated OS, but, for reference, the answer is that safe area insets were buggy on iOS 11. In some cases, as seen here, the window did not have correct safe area insets, but views lower in the window's view hierarchy did. In other cases, values were correct for notched devices (iPhone X) but not for others (e.g. iPhone 8 Plus). Most of these issues were ironed out in iOS 12 and completely fixed in iOS 13.